# Speed up End to End test by disabling 3rd party XHR calls

Tags: node.js, cypress

I'm doing a POC using cypress.io to write end to end test. Can I  disable 3rd party XHR calls like chat or analytics to reduce page response time? I initially thought to stub such calls but as per their documentation, stubbing xhr response will actually slow down page loading. So is there any direct api or way to cancel such calls to speed up page loading?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress provides the way to [blacklist calls](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#blacklistHosts) which can be defined in the configuration. However, it is set as an application-level, not at the scenario level.